# CalendarProvider: querying Calendars by multiple IDs will return an empty cursor

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I want to query calendars from the CalendarProvider API. In the settings of my application, the user can check and uncheck which calendars he wants to use within my application. I am using a table `USEDCALENDARS`which got the columns _id (int), calendar_id (int) and used (int).

Now I want to show a Spinner that contains every writable calendar that the user selected. My approach is: Collect all calendar_ids from USEDCALENDARS where used = 1 (true). Then query the CalendarProvider with the collected ids as a queryparam. See me code here.

```
    //using a simple list as calendarIds because the code that collects the id is working perfectly
    List<Long> calendarIds = Arrays.asList(1L,2L,3L);
    String selection = Calendars._ID + " IN (?)";
    String joinedCalendarIds = StringUtils.join(calendarIds, ", ");

    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
            joinedCalendarIds
    };
    return cr.query(Calendars.CONTENT_URI, GOOGLE_CALENDARS_PROJECTION, selection,selectionArgs, Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME);
```

This is returning an empty cursor. But if you exchange the first line of the code with. `List<Long> calendarIds = Arrays.asList(1L);` (basicly limiting the amount of ids to 1), the correct calendar will be returned.

Am I going in the wrong direction? Why is this not working? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the issue is with how the paramneterised **IN** clause is resolved.

I did a few tests (4) as  per the following code :-

```
    String[] selectionargs = {"1","2","3"};
    String[] oldselectionargs = {"1,2,3"};
    SQLiteDatabase db = mydbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String oldselection = "_id IN(?)";
    String selection =  "_id" + " IN (";
    String selection4 = "_id IN (";
    for (int i=0; i < selectionargs.length; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            selection = selection + ", ";
        }
        selection = selection + selectionargs[i];
    }
    selection = selection + ")";
    String[] columns = {mydbhelper.MYFLOATCOL};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(mydbhelper.TESTFLOATTABLE,columns,selection,null,null,null,null);
    Log.d("DBIN","Cursor Count=" + cursor.getCount());
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Log.d("DBIN",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(mydbhelper.MYFLOATCOL)));
    }

    Cursor cursor2 = db.query(mydbhelper.TESTFLOATTABLE,columns,oldselection,oldselectionargs,null,null,null);
    Log.d("DBIN","Cursor Count=" + cursor2.getCount());
    while (cursor2.moveToNext()) {
        Log.d("DBIN",cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex(mydbhelper.MYFLOATCOL)));
    }

    Cursor cursor3 = db.query(mydbhelper.TESTFLOATTABLE,columns,
            "_id IN (" + oldselectionargs[0].toString() + ")",null,null,null,null);
    Log.d("DBIN","Cursor Count=" + cursor3.getCount());
    while (cursor3.moveToNext()) {
        Log.d("DBIN",cursor3.getString(cursor3.getColumnIndex(mydbhelper.MYFLOATCOL)));
    }

    for (int i=0; i < selectionargs.length; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            selection4 = selection4 + ",";
        }
        selection4 = selection4 + "?";
    }
    selection4 = selection4 + ")";

    Cursor cursor4 = db.query(mydbhelper.TESTFLOATTABLE,columns,selection4,selectionargs,null,null,null);
    Log.d("DBIN","Cursor Count=" + cursor4.getCount());
    while (cursor4.moveToNext()) {
        Log.d("DBIN",cursor4.getString(cursor4.getColumnIndex(mydbhelper.MYFLOATCOL)));
    }

    cursor.close();
    cursor2.close();
    cursor3.close();
    cursor4.close();
```

The output from the above code :-

```
07-14 13:55:54.717 23634-23634/? D/DBIN: Cursor Count=3
07-14 13:55:54.717 23634-23634/? D/DBIN: 100
07-14 13:55:54.717 23634-23634/? D/DBIN: 200
07-14 13:55:54.717 23634-23634/? D/DBIN: 300
07-14 13:55:54.718 23634-23634/? D/DBIN: Cursor Count=0
07-14 13:55:54.720 23634-23634/? D/DBIN: Cursor Count=3
07-14 13:55:54.720 23634-23634/? D/DBIN: 100
07-14 13:55:54.720 23634-23634/? D/DBIN: 200
07-14 13:55:54.720 23634-23634/? D/DBIN: 300
07-14 13:55:54.721 23634-23634/? D/DBIN: Cursor Count=3
07-14 13:55:54.721 23634-23634/? D/DBIN: 100
07-14 13:55:54.721 23634-23634/? D/DBIN: 200
07-14 13:55:54.721 23634-23634/? D/DBIN: 300
```

So the 1st, 3rd and 4th methods work (i.e. cursor, cursor3 and cursor4 return the expected values), the 2nd passing "1,2,3" as a parameter doesn't work (i.e. the way you tried).

- The 1st, using cursor1, uses an array of values and builds a comma
  delimited string that is included in the selection with
  `selectionargs` as null.
- The 2nd, using cursor2, is basically what
  you tried.
- The 3rd just uses a hard coded string i.e. really no
  different from the 1st)
- The 4th builds the WHERE (IN) clause with the appropriate number of parameters to be passed e.g. `.... IN (?,?,?)` and uses the `selectionargs` array as originally defined.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I just came to post that I found the answer by myself and this was the issue!